# I may have uninstalled everything

Tags: apt, uninstall

I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` and watched as literally everything including Software Center was slowly removed. I'm new and was slow to stop it in time. Now when I boot in my desktop shows just my background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you see your desktop press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

This will reinstall the desktop and its application set including software center.

If you can't run the command because you also removed the package manager then I am afraid reinstalling Ubuntu is your only option.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this was the answer you were looking for, please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to identify to correct answer and if not please say why.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the same media(live USB) to install Ubuntu all over again(it will be easy) as grub, partitions and everything is already done. Though i fail to understand why it removed almost everything?

Comment: The reason it removed everything I think was because I was root. I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can recover what you have already removed. You can reinstall Ubuntu without formating your partition, hoping that most configurations you had will be kept.